# How to include provision for AssertError?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, assert, assertions

I am doing df.query('someColumn > 0'). The solution checker is showing there is an AssertError. Any thoughts on how that can be handled?

Comment: That depends; what is the assertion that is failing, exactly?

Comment: "AssertionError: The resulting amount of should be someINTvalue".

This is the error that is being displayed.

Comment: @chepner - any thoughts?